# Max HR lower than others, what does it mean?

Tags: heart-rate, target-heart-rate

I am 41 and do a lot of cycling. I have not been physical fit all my life but I have really gotten into biking over the last year, I get out most days and somedays I have been out for 7 hours. This is mountain biking and its all VERY hilly due to the area I live in so its is always demanding.

I cycling with people the same age some older and although we are the same pace etc there HR goes higher than mine? they can hit 180, I never go above 160. I tend to be around 155 for most of the ride.

What does this mean? does my HR not peak as high as I have not been fit all my life.

edit -
My resting HR is low, sometimes just under 50 but norms 50 to 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal that the max. HR of different people is different. There are just people whith a higher HR than others, and the other way round.
You really shouldn't worry too much about your HR.

Your max. HR is higher than 160 if you get an average of 155 in a longer biking tour.

If you want to find out your max. HR you could google a good way to this while biking. As formulas don't consider individual prepositions concerning the HR they are not a good choice.

I'm not a biker, but a good way to find out your max. HR in running is to run a 10k race at your fastest pace and trying to do a sprint at the last few meters. The HR behind the finishing line should be pretty close to your max. HR. The way to do it with a bike should be pretty similar, but there are also other ways to do it.

Comment: If I am climbing, say a 1 in 4 hill my HR can hit 160 then I start to feel a little dizzy. Maybe 160 is my max :) thanks btw.